# Consume WCF service with dataContract as a parameter from PHP

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I am trying to consume a WCF service from a PHP client without success.
I am unable to consume service method which has a "DataContract" object as Parameter.
Here is my code:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

Below is "CompositeType" contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Below is the PHP Client I have created

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->BoolValue = true;
$obj->StringValue ="Sandeep";
$parameter= array("CompositeType"=>$obj);
echo "\n";
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:2051/Service1.svc?wsdl');
$obj1 = $client->GetDataUsingDataContract($parameter);
print_r($obj1);
```

When I use the above, DataContarct is passed as Null to WCF.

What is the solution?

Comment: What version of .Net are you working with? .net 3.5, or 4.0? Can you please post the <system.serviceModel> node from your asp.net web.config.

Comment: Please share the config bits for both client and server.

Answer (score 3):

```
$parameter= array("CompositeType"=>$obj);
```

change CompositeType in composite (= exact the same as variable name in the interface)